# beforeSave request undefined - cloud code bug?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Very strange, android code:

```
ParseObject t = new ParseObject("Test");
t.put("test","test");
t.save();
```

It works.

If I add a beforeSave cloud code, all fields will be undefined!

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Test", function(request, response) {
    console.log("request id:"+request.object.id);
    response.success();
});

I2015-09-12T14:53:24.099Z]v33 before_save triggered for Test for user yai2bFOzPt:
  Input: {"original":null,"update":{"ACL":{"*":{"read":true,"write":true},"yai2bFOzPt":{"read":true,"write":true}},"test":"test"}}
  Result: Update changed to {}

I2015-09-12T14:53:24.163Z]request id:undefined
```

If I delete the cloud code trigger it works again.

This behaviors only in a newly created parse application, old applications works!

Comment: Have you found any work around for the above issue.

Comment: Yes. I changed the "jssdk" value to 1.4.2 in the .parse.project file (or in the config/global.json "parseVersion")